# Extremely basic: Switching between Activities (Android)

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hey, I realize there are tutorials on this topic, and even previous questions posed.  However, I've read several tutorials and some answers and I am still having trouble. Clearly, I must not be the brightest crayon in the box.

My program crashes when I try to switch between activities with the following code:

```
    final Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_mode);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent runOptionSelect = new Intent(TheDecider.this, OptionSelect.class);
            startActivity(runOptionSelect);
            return;
        }
    });
```

I think this code is fine so it must be an issue with the manifest.xml right?  I don't understand when to use which activity constant.  If my purpose is simply to switch to a different layout and class, what should I choose?

Also, are MAIN and LAUNCHER only to be used on the initial activity to be run?

So sorry for asking such a basic question but I've spent far too much time researching this to no avail.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know diddly about Android development, but congratulations on a well-asked question.  Clear and complete.

Comment: Can you post your logcat results. Maybe you can paste your manifest.xml

Comment: Post the stack trace from your log output. If you just mean to switch the layout its probably easier to call setContentView() and pass in your new layout xml file. You are also calling return from a void method. I am not sure if this would give you a force close but you might take that out just in case.

Comment: The return statement didn't affect anything, it seems.  Just FYI, in case you see someone use it for a void method again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check below code in your manifest.xml file

---

```
<activity android:name=".TheDecider"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <activity android:name=".OptionSelect"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Comment: So I should use DEFAULT whenever I wish to just use an Activity as a switch-to screen? (Thanks for this answer.  However, I seem to have an additional problem.)

Comment: @BlackVegetable yes when you just wish use an Activity then use DEFAULT. if you find this answer is helpful then kindly vote.

Comment: I would love to, but I am lacking the needed 15 reputation.  Sorry.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

In the intent, the first parameter is the current context (you can do

```
TheDecider.this
```

or

```
getApplicationContext()
```

there) and the second one is the class from the activity you are trying to reach.

You are doing that right. And in your manifest you should add

```
<activity android:name=".OptionSelect"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

You have to add EVERY Activity in your Manifest, otherwise it will crash. Without knowing your logcat's content, that's all i can say.

Comment: How can I access the logcat you mention?  (Thanks to you too.)

Comment: Is there a good walkthrough you could link to for using the ADB?  I assume this is how you access the logcat.

Comment: ADB is included in Eclipse Plugin, so all you have to do is go to the debug view and choose logcat there.